# Adding a target='blank' attribute in D7 module for Nice Menus

Tags: routes

I'm trying to add a `target=_blank` to all of the menu items inside [Nice Menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus). Has anyone ever figured this out?

I suspect that it's like adding title tag but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [menu attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module to add additional attributes with your particular menu item:

> This simple module allows you to specify some additional attributes
>   for menu items such as id, name, class, style, and rel.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure if it integrates with nice menu. You'll have to give it a try nonetheless.